# Error L_ERRORCODE0=10486 returned from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Let me try to explain the situation. Our site provide a payment via paypal, DoExpressCheckoutPayment method.
We tested the payment via the sandbox and everything is working fine.

Once we switch to production, the customer cannot make a payment and we get the following in our logs :

> Response nvpresp=TIMESTAMP=2016%2d05%2d16T03%3a51%3a20Z&
>       CORRELATIONID=b6e9d55427207&ACK=Failure&VERSION=56&BUILD=22120179&
>       L_ERRORCODE0=10486&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20couldn%27t%20be%20completed%2e&
>       L_LONGMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20couldn%27t%20be%20completed
>       %2e%20Please%20redirect%20your%20customer%20to%20PayPal%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

This issue was not happening a week ago.

My understanding is that the error 10486 is the same as the 10417 but it allows us to send the customer back to paypal, which we are not doing.

Does this mean the payment fails on paypal side, or this issue is coming from our server?

Thank you very much for your comments/answers.

Answer (score 1):

We finally found what was the issue.

In case the customer has its credit card blocked by the bank, this is the error returned by PayPal. In other words, the issue at the customer side.

I hope this will help somebody looking for the same issue.